# How can I find the occurrence of compound words in a text

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find the occurrence of specific words or compound words in a text.

For example,The text is " Happy Birthday to you"
And the phrase I have to match is "Happy Birthday".

I have a dictionary of words/phrases that needs to be matched against the input text. This dictionary consists of about 3000 words/compound words. The number of texts that need to be analysed may vary. Right now I am using a regex .*\b+phrase+\b.*. This gives me the right answer but is slow.

Also,it might be possible that the word that is to be found in the text is preceded or followed by special characters like !,:,. etc.

Although text.contains() is fast, I cannot use it because it returns true even for a subset of the word. Is there any way I can do this faster?

Comment: Why can't you use `text.contains()`? What do you mean by subset of the word?

Comment: Where are you storing dictionary?

Comment: Like say, the word I want to find is author,then contains would return true even for authority which is wrong.

Comment: @Sudhanshu : I am using an ArrayList for the dictionary.

Comment: Split by whitespace (s.split("\\s+"), do .equals("author") on the array.

Comment: Can't you combine the two approaches? So use `text.contains` first, and only if that returns true, use the slower regex.

Comment: @user948652 : I can't split by whitespace because I may have compund words like New York to match.

Comment: @Heuster:Yes,that would indeed be better.However,in a situation where all the i/p texts contain the keyword it will not be beneficial.

Comment: True, that completely depends on your input set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the string to an array of words and use the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), but instead of comparing characters in a string, you compare words in an array.

For example, the string:

```
i bought a hat in manhattan
```

split it into the array:

```
S = {"i","bought","a","hat","in","manhattan"}
```

If you are looking for a single word, simply compare the word you are looking for with every word in this array.

If you are looking for a sequence of words, for example:

```
W = {"a","hat","in"}
```

Use KMP. Explicitly, refering to the algorithm as defined by wikipedia, set S and W as above, and when the algorithm states `if W[i] = S[m + i]`, you implement this in java by:

```
if(W[i].equals(S[m+i]))
```

Comment: Hey,I was trying this out with KMP and Boyer-Moore as well.However,both these algorithms return true even if the word exists with other letters appended. eg. Say,I want to find hat and the text contains man"hat"tan,then the algo returns true.Any clue how can I handle this without using a regex?

Comment: The point is to split the string in to an array of words first, I'll add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (" " + test + " ").contains(" " + phrase + " ");

This should cover three conditions -

When test string starts with phrase or ends wit phrase, still our contains will find the string.
When phrase in the middle, it will find the phrase.
When the phrase contains space, still we are fine...

Can't think of any other case...

Comment: :Thanks.This would work in cases where there are no special characters like ,! etc. immediately following the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a lot of `indexOf()` and `substring()` methods of `java.lang.String`, which may lower the *performance* of the code, but below code can be taken as the first step towards this approach.

```
public class MultiWordCompare {

    private static boolean containsWord(String word, String search) {
        if(word.indexOf(search) >= 0) { // Try if the word first exists at all
            try {
                String w = word.substring(word.indexOf(search), word.indexOf(search)+search.length()+1); //+1 to capture possible space
                if(w.lastIndexOf(" ") == w.length()-1) { //if the last char is space, then we captured the whole word
                    w = w.substring(0, w.length()-1); //remove space
                    return w.equals(search); //do string compare
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //catching IndexOutofBoundException
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(containsWord("New York is great!", "New York"));
        System.out.println(containsWord("Many many happy Returns for the day", "happy Returns"));
        System.out.println(containsWord("New Authority", "New Author"));
        System.out.println(containsWord("New York City is great!", "N Y C"));
    }

}
```

And here's the output

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed this in the question;but it is quite possible that the i/p text has special characters like New York! is great or even I love New York.

Comment: As I said, this is not a complete solution and just an approach. You can start adding more handling with this initial piece of code. Probably I am assuming there is `space` after each word.. you can enhance this code to handle more stuffs

Answer (score 0):

```
     String text    =
                "This is the text to be searched " +
                 "for occurrences of the http:// pattern.";

     String patternString = "This is the";

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

     System.out.println("lookingAt = " + matcher.lookingAt());
     System.out.println("matches   = " + matcher.matches());
```

Source from the below url. For more details check the below url once.

[Matcher](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html)